# What is the meaning of "/.cache/" in a path or directory?

Tags: command-line, find, cache, xdg-base-directory

I was looking for a file "file.odt" so I used the find command:

```
sudo find / -name "file.odt"
```

While my computer came up with several paths to a number of copies of the same file, it also came up with a path that looks like this:

> /home/user/.cache/.fr-ShFl2I/file.odt

Needless to say, there is no folder called **".cache"** in "user". What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 5):

The dot `.` at the start of a file name marks a file as hidden, which is why you don't see it.

In Files (Nautilus), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to show hidden files. Or from the menu: *View* >> *Show hidden files* .

In a terminal, you can use `ls -a` to show all files, including hidden files.

The `/home/<user>/.cache` directory is commonly used by programs to store information that is specific to the user.

The `.cache` is intended to be used as an area for a program's temporary or working data. In practice, however, it is still a good idea to understand how a program uses its data in the `/.cache` before deleting it.

Comment: `~/.cache/` is used for temporary/intermediate working data; I wouldn't really call it “information” but more like scratch paper that you (can) throw away after you are done.

Comment: Yes, but over the years I've noticed some progs keep more permanent info in there. But it's a good comment and I'll add it in.

Comment: While data is often kept for longer because that saves time on the next run, deleting it should have no adverse effects (e.g. keeping thumbnails of pictures there avoids having to re-thumbnail them, but if you delete them it is no problem to make new thumbnails).  And *if* applications keep important data there, you should certainly file bug reports with them.

Comment: Configuration should go under `~/.config/`, other data should probably go under `~/.local/`.

Comment: I don't see it as that clear cut. For example, when I change the wallpaper, Unity stores the file in .cache. And there are other cases. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I'm addressing the situation as it really is in practice, not as the standard says it should be. In practice there just isn't always a clear distinction between the two dirs.

Comment: Nautilus keeps a temporary copy of the background there, but the configuration points to the original file, so you can delete the file in `~/.cache/wallpaper/` if you want.

Comment: @JanC Yes, after using that example I looked into it further and realized that was I was incorrect on that one. But I'm not going to argue point by point. I made a general statement that I think is true: programs don't always respect the difference and you shouldn't feel that anything in .cache is safe to get rid of. I stand by this view. Plus the answer is about about the dot, not the purpose of the cache. I added that just as a general warning that I think is fair as it stands. :)

Comment: @JanC Ok, I kept the warning but softened the other language.

Answer (score 3):

The `~/.cache/` directory is defined in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/latest/) to be used for “user-specific non-essential (cached) data”.  It's similar to what system-wide applications or services would put in `/var/cache/`.

The files in that directory are usually used by the application to make things go faster, to store logs or other data that can be useful to debug problems or recover from a crash, to keep a local version of data that can be (re-)downloaded from the network, etc.  Deleting them *while the application is not running* should not have serious effects, but it will often have *some* effect.

A good example is thumbnails: keeping them there makes the file manager a lot faster when viewing a directory with a lot of pictures that you visited before, but if you delete them it will simply recreate the thumbnails (which might take a long time if there are many images, of course).

The `.` at the front of a directory or file name makes it “hidden” on UNIX/Linux systems.  You can view hidden files in the default Ubuntu file manager by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, or *View* → *Show Hidden Files* in the menu (and the same to hide them again).  Many of the other hidden files or directories you will see that way contain configuration or other data (e.g. bookmarks, e-mail, etc.) that might be important for you, so **be careful not to delete those**!